# Specify Redshift schema for AWS Data Pipeline SqlActivity without adding "set search_path to ..." at beginning of sql script

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am building an AWS Data Pipeline which simply executes a bunch of sql scripts located on s3 on a Redshift EC2Resource. I need the scripts to run on the production schema rather than the testing one. Preferably I would do this without adding a "set search_path to schemaname" to each script. I need something like a "Connect Script" functionality (in SQL Workbench for example) which does this. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: workaround: i just wrote a script to prepend "set search path to schemaname" to each file and then upload it to the appropriate s3 bucket

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 part names for the tables, i.e., `schema.table`.

```
COPY my_schema.my_table
FROM 's3://…
```

If this is a shell script you can substitute the schema when you call the script. FWIW, we do this all the time.